# Croatia's reparations to Serbia after WWII

Tags: world-war-two, yugoslavia

How Croatia avoid to pay reparations to Serbia after the WWII for something like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II_persecution_of_Serbs)?

Answer (score 7):

Neither Croatia nor Serbia existed after the war and hence hey could neither pay nor receive reparations. Yugoslavia would have ended up paying reparations to Yugoslavia, which would have been fairly pointless.

Comment: So how this incident was handled after the WWII?

Comment: @user3646 Not at all: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II_persecution_of_Serbs#Aftermath